# Why does my render become so much dimmer after saving?

Tags: rendering, transparency

This screenshot pretty much sums it up:

[image]

The top image is a rendered image, being viewed in Blender's native render viewer. The bottom image is the result after being saved and viewed in any other program I've tried (Windows photo viewer, Photoshop, Discord, et cetera). It still happens when I save in 16 bit with 0% compression.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? I assume it has something to do with the way alpha layers are created and applied, but I don't know how to avoid or resolve it (aside from stacking duplicates of the dim part in a photo editing software).

Thanks in advance!

If it helps, here's a link to the file: [image]

Comment: Yeah definitely a problem with how it saves alpha.

Comment: Is there something I can do in Blender, or when saving, to avoid this issue? (I need a transparent background)

Comment: Because PNG and Photoshop mishandle alpha. Plain and simple.

Comment: I would recommend changing the color space with which the image is saved, and possibly with which it is loaded. I believe blender by default uses sRGB, But you can try linear or one of the other options. You could also try using a different format, such as openEXR.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thanks for responding. The only color space options for PNG in Blender are: B&W, RGB, or RGBA. I tried openEXR before posting and that didn't really help either.

Comment: No no, those are color channel options. I’m talking about color space. sRGB, linear, non-color data, something like that.